# Cannot read property 'conversationId' of undefined while using a reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Just to make it clear router uses the code below and my messages.js are inside api folder....
`router.use("/messages", require("./messages"));`
so my api call is correct.

Backend for posting the message.... I know conversationId will be null if no conversation exists but... I am trying to send message where conversation exists already and still I am getting cannot read the conversationId of undefined....

```
// expects {recipientId, text, conversationId } in body 
// (conversationId will be null if no conversation exists yet)
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
    const senderId = req.user.id;
    const { recipientId, text, conversationId, sender } = req.body;

    // if we already know conversation id, we can save time and just add it to message and return
    if (conversationId) {
      const message = await Message.create({ senderId, text, conversationId });
      return res.json({ message, sender });
    }
    // if we don't have conversation id, find a conversation to make sure it doesn't already exist
    let conversation = await Conversation.findConversation(
      senderId,
      recipientId
    );

    if (!conversation) {
      // create conversation
      conversation = await Conversation.create({
        user1Id: senderId,
        user2Id: recipientId,
      });
      if (onlineUsers.includes(sender.id)) {
        sender.online = true;
      }
    }
    const message = await Message.create({
      senderId,
      text,
      conversationId: conversation.id,
    });
    res.json({ message, sender });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

This is the frontend that posts the data to the backend....

```
const saveMessage = async (body) => {
  const { data } = await axios.post("/api/messages", body);
  return data;
};
```

---

Okay so here is detail information on how I am dispatching it.

```
class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "",
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // add sender user info if posting to a brand new convo, 
    // so that the other user will have access to username, profile pic, etc.
    const reqBody = {
      text: event.target.text.value,
      recipientId: this.props.otherUser.id,
      conversationId: this.props.conversationId,
      sender: this.props.conversationId ? null : this.props.user,
    };
    await this.props.postMessage(reqBody);
    this.setState({
      text: "",
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <form className={classes.root} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormControl fullWidth hiddenLabel>
          <FilledInput
            classes={{ root: classes.input }}
            disableUnderline
            placeholder="Type something..."
            value={this.state.text}
            name="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    );
  }
}


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(Input));



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    postMessage: (message) => {
      dispatch(postMessage(message));
    },
  };
};



// message format to send: {recipientId, text, conversationId}
// conversationId will be set to null if its a brand new conversation
export const postMessage = (body) => (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const data = saveMessage(body);

    if (!body.conversationId) {
      dispatch(addConversation(body.recipientId, data.message));
    } else {
      dispatch(setNewMessage(data.message));
    }

    sendMessage(data, body);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

So I have attached what I want to do here now....
But I am still getting the problem....

```
// CONVERSATIONS THUNK CREATORS, this is how I am getting data from the backend

export const fetchConversations = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/conversations");
    dispatch(gotConversations(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};


export const setNewMessage = (message, sender) => {
  return {
    type: SET_MESSAGE,
    payload: { message, sender: sender || null },
  };
};

// REDUCER

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CONVERSATIONS:
      return action.conversations;
    case SET_MESSAGE:
      return addMessageToStore(state, action.payload);
    case ADD_CONVERSATION:
      return addNewConvoToStore(
        state,
        action.payload.recipientId,
        action.payload.newMessage
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I am getting an error saying Cannot read property 'conversationId' of undefined while using a reducer function... Should I give the setintial value of the message to empty?

```
export const addMessageToStore = (state, payload) => {
  const { message, sender } = payload;
  // if sender isn't null, that means the message needs to be put in a brand new convo
  if (sender !== null) {
    const newConvo = {
      id: message.conversationId,
      otherUser: sender,
      messages: [message],
    };
    newConvo.latestMessageText = message.text;
    return [newConvo, ...state];
  }
  return state.map((convo) => {
    if (convo.id === message.conversationId) {
      const convoCopy = { ...convo };
      convoCopy.messages.push(message);
      convoCopy.latestMessageText = message.text;

      return convoCopy;
    } else {
      return convo;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: What is the `gotConversations` action?

Comment: Can you share where you dispatch `setNewMessage` and what the value of `message` is when you do? It seems that `message` is undefined.

Comment: Can you add that to your question? It's terribly difficult to read code in comments if it spans more than a single line.

Comment: I just did it... Is there anything wrong I did... I am not being able to figure out.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking for more, but what is `saveMessage` function doing with `body` and what is the verified `data` return value? Can you add these to your question? Is this a private endpoint?

Comment: SaveMessage is actually posting the data to the backend... I have an api made for messages.... I will include it to the post...

Comment: I just included the code there...

Comment: Ok, I think I see what the issue is now. I've updated my answer below. If this for some reason isn't the issue then let's please continue this in a chat if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

The `saveMessage` function is declared `async`

```
const saveMessage = async (body) => {
  const { data } = await axios.post("/api/messages", body);
  return data;
};
```

but the `postMessage` action creator isn't `async` so it doesn't wait for the implicitly returned Promise to resolve before continuing on and dispatching to the store. This means that `data.message` is undefined since a `Promise` object doesn't have this as a property.

```
export const postMessage = (body) => (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const data = saveMessage(body); // <-- no waiting

    if (!body.conversationId) {
      dispatch(addConversation(body.recipientId, data.message));
    } else {
      dispatch(setNewMessage(data.message));
    }

    sendMessage(data, body);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

## Solution

Declare `postMessage` `async` as well and `await` the `data` response value.

```
export const postMessage = (body) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const data = await saveMessage(body); // <-- await response

    if (!body.conversationId) {
      dispatch(addConversation(body.recipientId, data.message));
    } else {
      dispatch(setNewMessage(data.message));
    }

    sendMessage(data, body);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: I have attached all the method above if you want to check and codes what I am trying to do.... I have actually done the thing that you have said... and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I just did it @Drew. I just wanted to ask if you have seen any security issue on my postMessage api or frontend?

Comment: @PrakashTimalsina Hopefully you are implementing *some* authentication scheme and protect your endpoints/servers, but other than this, no, nothing jumps out to me as a severe security vulnerability.

Comment: I would like to learn more about securing my endpoints if you wanna have a chat somewhere in private. Thanks